# Illegal invocation with start/noteOn using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

So basically I've tested this in Chrome and maybe the order of codes is off or whatever, trying to cover some of the functionality of HTML5 audio using "web audio" due to the range requests bug, for the making of games with looping sound effects and music...

I get an "illegal exception" error. Here's the code:

```
    var url='example.mp3';

    var a_result=new Object();
    a_result.loaded=false;
    a_result.evalstring='';
    a_result.loop=false;
    a_result.play=function(){
        var asrc=a_result.source;
        asrc.loop=a_result.loop;
        //try{
            var playfunc=asrc.start||asrc.noteOn;
            playfunc(0);
        //}catch(e){
            /* do nothing */
        //}
    }
    a_result.pause=function(){
        var asrc=a_result.source;
        try{
            var stopfunc=asrc.stop||asrc.noteOff;
            stopfunc(0);
        }catch(e){
            /* do nothing */
        }
    }

    var asrc=actx.createBufferSource();
    asrc.connect(actx.destination);

    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET',url,true);
    req.responseType='arraybuffer';

    req.onload=function(){
        if(a_result.loaded==false){
            asrc.buffer=actx.createBuffer(req.response,false);
            a_result.source=asrc;
            a_result.loaded=true;
        }
        var cont=a_result;
        eval(cont.evalstring);
    }
    req.onerror = function() {
        if(a_result.loaded==false){
            a_result.loaded=true;
        }
    }
    try{
        req.send(null);
    }catch(e){
        req.onerror();
    }

    return a_result;
```

And then later on after the sound has loaded I do something like:

```
a_result.play();
```

And instead of playing it gives the error.

[Here](http://nextgengame.webs.com/data/soundtest.htm) is a sound test that uses the above code with the fix suggested below, and it works in Chrome, successfully working around the range requests issue on a crappy web server. [Here](http://nextgengame.webs.com/) is another that has issues (throwing some kind of "invalid string" error at asrc.buffer=actx.createBuffer(req.response,false); in Iron and silently screwing up in Chrome).

Here is the code edited according to the suggestions:

```
    var url='example.mp3'

    var a_result=new Object();
    a_result.loaded=false;
    a_result.evalstring='';
    a_result.loop=false;
    a_result.play=function(){
        var asrc=a_result.source;
        asrc.loop=a_result.loop;
        try{
            if(asrc.start){
                asrc.start(0);
            }else{
                asrc.noteOn(0);
            }
        }catch(e){
            /* do nothing */
        }
    }
    a_result.pause=function(){
        var asrc=a_result.source;
        try{
            if(asrc.stop){
                asrc.stop(0);
            }else{
                asrc.noteOff(0);
            }
        }catch(e){
            /* do nothing */
        }
    }

    var asrc=actx.createBufferSource();
    asrc.connect(actx.destination);

    var req=new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET',url,true);
    req.responseType='arraybuffer';

    req.onload=function(){
        actx.decodeAudioData(req.response,function(buffer){
            if(buffer){
                if(a_result.loaded==false){
                    asrc.buffer=buffer;
                    a_result.source=asrc;
                    a_result.loaded=true;
                }
                var cont=a_result;
                eval(cont.evalstring);
            }
        });
    }
    req.onerror = function() {
        if(a_result.loaded==false){
            a_result.loaded=true;
        }
    }
    try{
        req.send(null);
    }catch(e){
        req.onerror();
    }

    return a_result;
```

It no longer appears to have a syntax error, however, it does not seem to solve the playability issues on Chrome (second test case above updated). Specifically, after a sound is stopped it does not want to play again. -- Apparently because it's in the spec. The buffer has to be applied to a new sound source every time you play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your new page, you're calling createBuffer(data, false) on the results of an XMLHTTPRequest. You almost certainly want to be calling decodeAudioData() on those results, instead - createBuffer doesn't have a 2-parameter version, and doesn't match the parameters you're passing even if you're trying to push arbitrary data into a buffer.  It appears from a browse of your code that you're pulling down MP3 or Ogg files - you need to decode them.

Comment: Well, I got the idea from the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102513/web-audio-api-undefined-method-createbuffer-and-createbuffersource

Comment: So, I changed the code as you suggested, thereby getting rid of the syntax error in Iron (and probably improving standards compliance or something), but I still get the problem of sounds not playing after they are stopped (with the pause() function).

Comment: It looks like it's part of the spec to have to createBufferSource and all that right before you play a sound. I'll work on fixing it and accept this answer if it works.

Comment: You don't need to create the BufferSource *right* before you play it - but you do know that once you stop() a BufferSource, you need to throw it away and create a new one, right?  stop() is not a pause, and once a buffersource has been start()ed, it can't be start()ed again.  It's a one-shot playback.

The AudioBuffer can be reused as many times as you like, though, even simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

The play method (either start() or noteOn()) needs to be invoked ON the buffersourcenode object, not disassociated from it.  You have a few options:

1) I'd strongly recommend just including my audio context monkeypatch library (https://github.com/cwilso/AudioContext-MonkeyPatch/) and using the new (start()) syntax.  no muss, no fuss.

2) You can just use an if statement instead of using playfunc to switch:

```
if (asrc.start)
    asrc.start(0);
else
    asrc.noteOn(0);
```

3) You can bind() the play function to the object and keep your code essentially the same:

```
var playfunc=asrc.start ? asrc.start.bind(asrc) || asrc.noteOn.bind(asrc);
playfunc(0);
```

4) You can push the playfunc() method onto the object itself (I *think* this will work):

```
asrc.playfunc=asrc.start||asrc.noteOn;
asrc.playfunc(0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, however I am not sure if this completely solves the problem (see above).